# Where is this place from the movie The Occupant

Tags: the-occupant

[image]

Where does the story, *The Occupant*, take place? It does not mention it from the movie plotline. All I can find is this picture that may indicate which city it is.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie, but the picture shows the [skyline of __Hong Kong__](https://www.tripsavvy.com/five-best-places-to-view-hong-kong-harbor-1536059), one can prominently see the __[Bank of China Tower](https://www.britannica.com/topic/Bank-of-China-Tower)__, and to the right, you see a tiny bit of the __[Observation Wheel](https://www.discoverhongkong.com/eng/interactive-map/the-hong-kong-observation-wheel.html)__.

Comment: The title of your post and the contents do not ask the same thing. Either you want to know the place in that picture, or you want the location where the movie is taking place. And the location shown in that picture is irrelevant trivia WRT the movie.

Comment: yeah, that is what confused me. I realized it Hong Kong, but everyone spoke Spanish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt9345754/locations) suggests that Barcelona a city of Spain  was its place of shooting.

The plot suggests that

> It follows Javier Muñoz ... has been forced to surrender his swanky Barcelona apartment.

The directors, David Pastor and Álex Pastor, in an [interview](https://www.hitc.com/en-gb/2020/03/27/where-was-the-occupant-filmed-netflix-thrillers-location-reveale/) said,

> “In this case, we wanted to shoot it in Barcelona ....And we wanted to portray Spain and life in Spain after the crisis...”

Comment: I'm no Barcelona expert, but I doubt there's any part of the city where there's such a concentration of highrises and office buildings.

Comment: Since the comment in the OP suggests it is in Hong Kong, I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

The picture you posted is wildly misleading. The next shot clearly shows that it is an advert opposite the window of his apartment:

[image]

(You can see the lead character in the window on the right.)

Which is actually already clear because in the shot you screenshotted, the boats at the bottom don't move. Plus there is a flatness to it that wouldn't be there if this was a real panorama visible from his apartment.